# How to remember last ajax state when click back in browse

Tags: ajax

I have category browsing page initially shows 48 products, and after customers click a next button, it triggers ajax call to load next 48 products, so then the page has 96 products and the url keeps the same. And then, customers click one product from the page, and go to the product page, and then they click back in the browse going back to the browsing page, and the page is reloading and 24 products are shown.

So my question is that how to keep the last ajax state, so when customers click back, they still see 48 results.

I see LLBean can do it, but wondering how to implement this?
http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/509723?nav=ln-26&page=active-clothing

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "so when the customers click back" are you thinking that they use the back button embedded in their browser? Or a custom 'back' button on your product page?

Comment: back button embedded in their browser. thx!

Comment: clicking the back button changes the URL to a previously visited URL. If you are using AJAX to change content dynamically, you may have a problem.. Either have your next buttons navigate to new URL's or implement back buttons within the page.

Comment: Check LLBean link I provided in the post, you may know what I were talking about. After some researching, I think it may be accomplished by localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with either cookie storage on client side, or session data on server side. I guess I would recommend cookie storage since this is very basic insensitive data.

You can use the following code to write, read and erase cookie data:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

For example, you could set a cookie named `numResults` to store how many results the client is browsing:

```
var data = readCookie("numResults");
if (data != null && data != "") {
    //in this case, you have your data, load this many results
} else {
    createCookie("numResults", 48, 30); //create the cookie, if it doesn't already exist
}
```

And when you make the ajax call to increase results number, just add:

```
createCookie("numResults", newNumber, 30);
```